# Docker: why do I need to sudo in Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, sudo

I am working through [this tutorial](https://docker-curriculum.com/) setting up Docker, and I'm finding that all of their examples are written like

```
docker run hello-world
```

but when I try it, it says permission denied on a socket and I have to do

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

to run the examples. Why are root privileges necessary even for these simple examples?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: See also [How can I use Docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Running a docker container requires the user to be [a member of the `docker` group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall). By default, when you install docker, the only user that is added to it is `root`. You can add your own user to this group if you want to run docker containers from it.

Answer (score 11):

Requiring sudo-level access to get access to Docker is a sound security restriction. Otherwise, anyone who can run any Docker commands at all, can run this one:

```
docker run -v /etc:/host-etc busybox \
  sh -c 'echo ALL ALL(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL >> /host-etc/sudoers'
```

That is, anyone who can run Docker commands is all but `root` already.

Really this is controlled by the file permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock`.  Having a `docker` group that owns that socket file and giving it mode `0660` is a common setup (particularly on Ubuntu).  But, again, anyone who's a member of the `docker` group can read and change arbitrary files on the host, and is `root` in all but name.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it is the root user who owns the unix socket that binds with Docker daemon. So when you are trying without sudo, it give permission denied.

You can run without sudo with below steps by adding a user to a new created group docker:

Step 1: Create docker group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Step 2: Add your user to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Step 3: Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
Run this command to activate changes to groups:

```
newgrp docker
```

Now, it will work without sudo. Verify by running simple hello- world images:

```
docker run hello-world
```